# How can I read an attribute value of a svelte component

Tags: svelte

**Component.svelte**

```html
<script>
  export let hiddenStatus;
</script>

<div class:hidden={hiddenStatus}></div>
```

**App.svelte**

```html
<script>
  import Component from "./Component.svelte";
</script>

<Component hiddenStatus={true}/>
{Component.hiddenStatus}
```

When I try to get that attribute value of `hiddenStatus` it displays as `undefined`. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`bind:this` component directive](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-component-directives-bind-this) to interact with the component instance programmatically.

Note that props cannot be read directly from the component instance unless you are compiling with [`accessors` set to `true`](https://svelte.dev/docs#compile-time-svelte-compile) or [`<svelte:options accessors/>`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-options).

**Example**

```html
<!-- Component.svelte -->
<script>
  export let hiddenStatus;
</script>

<div class:hidden={hiddenStatus}></div>

<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import Component from "./Component.svelte";

  let component;
    
  onMount(() => {
    console.log(component.hiddenStatus);
  });
</script>

<Component hiddenStatus={true} bind:this={component}/>
```

Comment: For those wondering about the alternative to _"read[ing] directly from the component instance"_, it's [binding to the specific prop](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-bindings), i.e. `<Component bind:hiddenStatus={myVar}` or the shorthand `<Component bind:hiddenStatus`.